# Fetch size for each table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to fetch the size of each table in the database in Oracle

So I tried to do it in this way

**Reference**

```
 select
   table_name,
   to_number(
   extractvalue(
      xmltype(
         dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||table_name))
    ,'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) count
from 
   user_tables
order by 
   table_name;
```

**Tried Query**

```
select
   table_name,
   to_number(
   extractvalue(
      xmltype(
         dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select bytes/1024/1024 from user_segments where segment_name="' || table_name|| '"'))
    ,'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) count
from 
   user_tables
order by 
   table_name;
```

But I am unable to get it without for loop.

Comment: You don't need the XML stuff if you want to access columns directly available in `user_tables`. The XML "hack" is just a workaround to run a dynamic SQL inside of a regular query (without reverting to PL/SQL)

Comment: What about space for indexes?

Comment: If you really need to count the rows in each table rather than trusting the `num_rows` captured by `dbms_stats`, then some variation of `select count(*) * 10 from some_table sample block(10)` would give an approximate value more efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example can be done via join:

```
select
   a.table_name,
   b.bytes/1024/1024 as MB
from 
   user_tables a
join user_segments b
   on b.segment_name=a.table_name
order by 
   table_name;
```